# Is it possible to set the OG audience of a node to the audience of its referenced node using Rules?

Tags: organic-groups, rules

I'm working on a D7 helpdesk distro with four content types: Organization, Case, Internal Note, External Note. Notes are linked to a Case via node reference. To allow users to see only the Cases that belong to their Organization, each Organization is an Organic Group and each Case gets an Organization as its OG audience.

I plan to hide the OG piece on the Note form and have it automatically set to the same OG audience as its Case using a Rule. However, I can't seem to get the Rule written properly. Any advice?

Comment: did you find an answer ?

Comment: No, I never did. However my partners on the distro kind of disappeared after the first month of working on it, so the whole project stalled. I've seen that Rules and OG have both had improvements since I posted this in November, so it may actually be doable now.